# Is there an equivalent of django template comments for standalone JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, pycharm

I checked PyCharm knowledge base and "Google" but could not find if there is an equivalent to django template comments for "standalone" JavaScript files.

In Django, the following is not rendered when producing html pages (which also works for JavaScript code if it is in the template file):

```
{# this won't be rendered #}
// this will be rendered
```

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#comments

Because I would like to separate JavaScript code from the template (put it in *mySeparetedJsCode.js* and including it via a script tag), the django template `{# comment #}` does not work anymore.

does someone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a javascript minifier that will drop comments for you and do other space-saving measures, [Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) is a popular one that you can manually run on your js files when you deploy your code or anytime before that.

How to configure your minifier is application specific but with uglify it's controlled by the `preserveComments` directive, set `preservComments: "some"` which will  keep any comment that starts with a ! and the rest will be removed, set it to "all" and all comments will be removed.

The common solution is to have a javascript toolchain setup for this as you always want to serve minified files in production. djangos collect-static is a good place to have any automated process if you dont have a build system in place.

For example [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader), [django-pipeline](https://github.com/jazzband/django-pipeline) and [django-compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) are packages that already does this for you.

Comment: Your point is taken about using another server to serve static files, and in my daily work EVERYTHING sits behind a full scale web server, not just the static assets, but what does your proposed solution do to address the OP's question, which was essentially, "How do I remove some comments while leaving others?"

Comment: Also, could you at least provide links to the projects you mention?  EG googling "django-webpack" returns results, but nothing called "django-webpack", so to what package are you referring?

Comment: Thats answered in the first sentence. "What you want is a javascript minifier that will drop comments for you and do other space-saving measures" then it gives an example of such a minifier and how its commonly used. How to configure your minifier is application specific but in the case of uglify what comments to remove and what to keep is controlled by the preserveComments directive.

Comment: I guess the OP will need to decide if you have answered the question.  It seems to me that you've provided useful information, but still _not_ the answer to the question asked: "How do I remove SOME comments, but NOT others, like I can with Django".  Maybe you could expand on _how_ you would propose to do this with Webpack EG.